# Unable to apply ubuntu security update

Tags: ubuntu, security, updates

I ssh into my ubuntu server and see the following info:

```
215 updates can be installed immediately.
38 of these updates are security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable


2 updates could not be installed automatically. For more details,
see /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log
```

I run `sudo unattended-upgrade` to install the security updates but I get the following error:

```
Cache lock can not be acquired, exiting
```

Any ideas and how do I fix?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit old, but for those who land here like me, here is what I used.

```
# See actual lock files:
sudo ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

# Check if something is really running:
ps -ef | grep -v grep | egrep 'apt|dpkg'

# If so, wait for it (if very very long, maybe finally kill it).

# Remove lock files:
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

# Make sure packages are all ok:
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Now you should be able to run unattended-upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | egrep 'apt|dpkg'
```

to check if the `apt` command is running on other window.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).